# Raise the pH of a solution and prevent build up of carbonates

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

I need to *raise* the pH of a solution so the easiest approach is to add alkali hydroxides (NaOH, KOH, etc). But as most of you know, the CO$\ce{_2}$ in the air can react with these hydroxides to form carbonates which *usually*  precipitate out the other metal ion dissolved in the original solution. So what else are my options?

Answer (score 1):

How about $\ce{NH4OH}$? This does not for carbonates as readily, but it *does* form complexes with many metals. It depends on your intended use.

It might be easier to keep things away from the air:

1. Use a closed container.
2. Float an inert liquid (e.g. paraffin oil) atop your solution, or just a layer of pure water, which might take a while to mix.
3. Use an inert gas over the container to displace air.